How to create a 3D house in Flutter with rotation, highlighting, and control?
I want to create an app in Flutter or FlutterFlow with a 3D model of a house. (I’ve attached a picture below to make my idea clearer.)
Here are the tasks I need to implement:
The user should be able to rotate the house (to view it from different angles).
Below the house, there should be text with the names of the elements: "Facade," "Roof," "Back Wall," etc.
A "Next" button should:
Highlight the required element (e.g., the chimney turns green).
Automatically rotate the house so that the required part is in the foreground.
I plan to use Flutter or FlutterFlow, but there’s no native support for 3D graphics there.
How can I make this?
I don’t know anything about 3D, so please explain in detail
image example
I tried using Flutter to create a 3D model and searched for plugins or libraries that support 3D rendering. I expected to find a ready-made solution for working with 3D graphics, but couldn’t find anything suitable. I need help choosing the right tool or example for implementation.

how come this is tagged as [tag:unity-game-engine]? the entire post doesn't mention that once.

If you need to use it in Mobiles I sugest you start with Unity Engine to create the 3D side. 3D models if you don't know how to modeling like in Blender, you can buy online or even for free like in Sketchfab.
After it you can embbed it in your Flutter project using packeges like

https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_embed_unity/latest/
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_unity_widget

You can create a communication between scripts from Unity embbed and Flutter and create rotations, selectable parts and more.
